# printout the sql statement built from SQLiteQueryBuilder

Tags: android, sql

To facilitate debugging, is there any way print out a sql statement before executing following query?

```
        c = qb.query(
                 epgDB, 
                 projection, 
                 selection, 
                 selectionArgs, 
                 null, 
                 null, 
                 sortOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already used specific SQLiteQueryBuilder methods, e.g. appendWhere(), you can generate the underlying SQL statement simply by calling `buildQuery()`:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

// call qb.appendWhere(), qb.appendColumns(), qb.setProjectionMap() etc.

String sql;
sql = qb.buildQuery(null,  null, null, null, null, null, null); // pre API 11
sql = qb.buildQuery(null,  null, null, null, null, null); // API 11 and later
```

Both methods combine the parameters previously set by individual methods with their own parameters before calling `buildQueryString()`. They do not change the state of the SQLiteQueryBuilder object and so are safe to use before executing the query.

**A word of caution**: I learnt this from the code itself, while the javadoc does not mention using this method to get the SQL string. Hence, I advise to be alert of changes that would alter the behavior of the method.